# How to implement this i am not getting any output

Tags: jquery, json

need to extract json details into jquery

```
$("#btn-id").click(function() {
  $.getJson(g, function(jd) {
    $("#data-id").html(jd.id + "--" + jd.email);
  });
});
```

Comment: what is `$("data-id")` - add HTML as well.

Comment: your json is returning an object with a `data` property. That is an array so you will have to looop through it.

Comment: I cant understand can u please solve

Comment: added the html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function to loop through your data and then use [.append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) to show all the `ids` and `emails` in your `data-id` div.

Using `.html` will only display the last result from the loop.

**Demo:**

```js
$("#btn-id").click(function() {
  //get data    
  $.getJSON("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2", function(json) {
    //Empty div if clicked agian
    $("#data-id").html('')
    //loop through it
    json.data.forEach(function(jd) {
      //append data in div 
      $("#data-id").append(jd.id + "--" + jd.email + '<br>');
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>The jQuery Example</title>
  <!--     <script src="country.js"></script>
     -->
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="button" id="btn-id" value="Click to Load Data" />
    <div id="data-id"></div>
  </form>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <!--     <script src="country.js"></script>
     -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Sudharshan see the updated answer. We can just use `function` instead of arrow `=>` function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68401072/i-m-getting-the-output-but-test-case-fails/68401280#68401280 bro can you solve this also..i am getting output but the test case fails